# Getting ArgumentException "The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string" when using Enterprise Library Email Trace Listener

Tags: c#

I'm using Enterprise Library 6.0.  When I'm using the Email Trace Listener, I get an `ArgumentException`

> The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.

My configuration:

```
<add name="Email Trace Listener" 
     type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
     listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
     toAddress="testemail1@test.org;testemail2@test.org;" 
     subjectLineStarter="IMD.PP" 
     subjectLineEnder="Local" 
     fromAddress="testfrom@test.org" 
     smtpServer="smtpserver.test.org" 
     formatter="Text Formatter" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The cause was the extra semi-colon at the end of the toAddress, when I removed that semi-colon, it started working:

`<add name="Email Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" toAddress="testemail1@test.org;testemail2@test.org" subjectLineStarter="IMD.PP" subjectLineEnder="Local" fromAddress="testfrom@test.org" smtpServer="smtpserver.test.org" formatter="Text Formatter" />`

Comment: I know I'm answering my own question but I spent a lot of time searching for the answer to this and could not find any.  So after I fixed the issue I thought I'd post it here to hopefully save someone else some time.